# Error: Error in grouped_df_impl(data, unname(vars), drop)

Tags: r, group-by, tidyverse

> Error in grouped_df_impl(data, unname(vars), drop) :

```
library(tidyverse)
data <- read_csv("Data/data.csv")
col1 <- data$Month
col2 <- data$Alpha
data %>%
      group_by(col1)
```

Just trying to use the group_by function but error message displayed.

Comment: Please edit your question removing the `rm` call and adding sample data using `dput`. We have no access to your data currently.

Comment: Also do this data=data.frame(Col1=col1,Col2=col2). I'm typing on my phone so can't add a detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what happens:

```
library(tidyverse)
iris1<-iris
col1<-iris$Species
col2<-iris$Sepal.Length
iris1 %>% 
  group_by(col1)
```

This gives us:

> Error in grouped_df_impl(data, unname(vars), drop) : 
>     Column `col1` is unknown

Reason?
You're passing a column not present in the `data.frame`. In the `tidyverse` you don't use `$`
Solution:

```
iris1 %>% 
  group_by(Species)
```

Perfect!
Output:

```
# A tibble: 150 x 5
# Groups:   Species [3]
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>  
 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa 
 2          4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa 
 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa 
 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa 
 5          5           3.6          1.4         0.2 setosa 
 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4 setosa 
 7          4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3 setosa 
 8          5           3.4          1.5         0.2 setosa 
 9          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2 setosa 
10          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1 setosa
```

Comment: Thankyou for your answer.

Comment: Why is it that you never accept answers to your questions?